Double 6x6 Beam
I have a patio with a 6x6 beam supported on the left side and in the center with 6x6 posts. The right side has a metal hanger to connect it to the house. I would like to remove the center post. The span is 18 feet and is on a single story home. It is supporting only the patio ceiling and roof.
Since the patio ceiling is enclosed I would rather not tear into it to replace the existing beam. Can I insert a second 6x6 under the existing beam creating a 6x12 beam and remove the center support? What would be the best way to connect the two 6x6 beams together?
I would cut the left post shorter to allow the new 6x6 to sit on top of it. I would replace the metal hanger on the right with the 6x6 post I removed from the center. I would end up with a 6x12 beam sitting on 6x6 posts on each end.
Any feedback and wisdom would be greatly appreciated.

Three 2x12sx18 might be much cheaper that one 6x6x18.  Stacked wood is not stronger compared to multi single planks side by side bonded together.

Modifications to structural features of your home carry heavy risks. When beam supports are placed, they're usually numbered in such a way to support both the dead load (the weight of the structure itself) and the live load (the weight of rain/snow/people/forceful wind/etc.) that is reasonable to expect on the structure.
If I understand your description, the patio is supported by a 6x6 beam resting on 2 6x6 posts and a wall hanger on the house itself. Your goal is to replace the wall hanger with the central post, doubling the thickness of the beam to compensate.
I wouldn't classify this as a DIY type of project. While you can certainly do it yourself with a little knowhow, you're doing a couple things to the roof structure that would definitely worry me.

You're doubling the effective support length of the span from ~8.5 feet to ~17 feet. The compensation of doubling the beams thickness likely won't offset the additional sag from the new length between supports (hard to say without knowing exactly what wood/supporting mechanism).

You're increasing the overall weight of the roof (extra 18 feet of 6x6), while removing 1/3 of the supporting structure. While this may not be a problem per se (it depends on the safety factor built in) this will probably bring you a lot closer to those live/dead load limits I mentioned at the top of the answer, if not exceeding them.

With that extra weight and reduced support, you're going to get more lateral force on the support structure. The weight presses down with gravity, but the material and roof design will translate some of that force into lateral force as well. The moved central post will be backed up by the home wall, and likely won't shift, but it's entirely possible the outer post may start tipping at the top as the roof sags along the span.


If you want to be sure, spend a little to get your new plan reviewed by a structural engineer. Be sure your HOI and local building code don't prevent this scale of work by an unlicensed DIY'er either.
EDIT: I slept on it and came up with one more concern:
The wall hanger anchors the patio roof to the wall of the home, but replacing it, you are effectively detaching the roof section and leaving it 'floating' this could be very, very bad if there isn't another support structure in place to tie it to the main structure.

nice one +1.......

Excellent answer. It's easy for any of us to look up a material strength table and assume our proposed changes are fine, but the value of an expert is seeing implications across other elements of a structure. Even the professionals can sometimes overlook things: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyatt_Regency_walkway_collapse#Investigation
